# Define an array of nested movieclips

Tags: arrays, flash, nested, movieclip

I have 2 `movieclips(mc1, mc2)` nested inside a `movieclip(container)` who is nested inside another `movieclip(main)`.

```
(mc1 & mc2 -> container -> main)
```

How can I define an array for those 2 `movieclips(mc1 mc2)` so that it can be used in the main timeline?

E.g: if the 2 `movieclips` were on stage then `var theArray:Array = [mc1, mc2]`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
var theArray:Array = [main.container.mc1, main.container.mc2];
```

Comment: yes it is working, but when i try to add a CLICK event to mc1 and mc2, it give me error. Something like this: theArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener)

Comment: A term is undefined and has no property

Comment: I figure it out: main.container.theArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener). Now it works